# unable to post empty image file in nodejs using multer

Tags: node.js, multer, image-upload

I want to post a form with or without image file. I am able to upload image file but it sends me error while trying to upload without image fiel
my code is

```
  router.post('/fabric', upload.any([{
  name: 'image', maxCount:1}, {
    name: 'design'
  }]), (req, res, next) => {
  const io = req.app.get('io');

  const product = new db.fabric({
    image: req.protocol + "://" + req.hostname + ":" + req.socket.localPort + "/img/" + req.files[0].filename,
    mobilenumber: req.body.mobilenumber,
    email: req.body.email,
    design: req.protocol + "://" + req.hostname + ":" + req.socket.localPort + "/img/" + req.files[1].filename
  });

  product.save().then(result => {
    res.status(201).json({
      message: "product added successfully!",
      productCreated: {
        image: result.image,
        design: result.design,
        mobilenumber: result.mobilenumber,
        email: result.email
      }
    })
    io.emit('productAdded');
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err),
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
  })
})
```

when i post from postman without image fiel i got following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply check

```
    const product = new db.fabric({
    image: req.files.length>0 && req.files[0]?req.protocol + "://" + req.hostname + ":" + req.socket.localPort + "/img/" + req.files[0].filename:"",
    mobilenumber: req.body.mobilenumber,
    email: req.body.email,
    design: req.files.length>0 && req.files[1]?req.protocol + "://" + req.hostname + ":" + req.socket.localPort + "/img/" + req.files[1].filename:""
  });
```

also make sure that in db image and design is not mandatory field